# How to get Instagram following list using http component in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, instagram, delphi-10-seattle, idhttp

I'm trying to get my instagram "following" list using only http component. I've tried to use `lHTTP.Get('https://www.instagram.com/Myusername/following/');` but there are no usernames in the decrypted html. However, I saw some guys using it without instagram api, just http response in VB.Net. I'm using Delphi 10.

**UPDATE**

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Params, login : TStrings;
  Reply, Token, X: string;
  Cookie: TIdCookie;
 begin

try
Params := TStringList.Create;
Params.Add('username=' + Edit1.Text);
Params.Add('password=' + Edit2.Text);

lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
try
  IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
  IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
  lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
  lHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
  lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
  lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36';
  lHTTP.Get('https://www.instagram.com', TStream(nil));
  Cookie := lHTTP.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Cookie['csrftoken', 'www.instagram.com'];
  if Cookie <> nil then
    Token := Cookie.Value;

  try
  lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-CSRFToken'] := Token;
  lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Instagram-AJAX'] := '1';
  lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Requested-With'] := 'XMLHttpRequest';
  lHTTP.Request.Referer := 'https://www.instagram.com/';
  lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36';
  Reply := lHTTP.Post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', Params);

  finally
  end;

  finally
  end;

Finally

  lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36';
  lHTTP.Get('https://www.instagram.com/myusername/following/', TStream(nil));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Reply);


     Finally
    end;
end;



 end;
```

Comment: Anything you can with HTTP in VB.Net, you can do with `TIdHTTP` in Delphi. Please show the actual code you have tried that is not working for you. This is not unlike your [other Instagram issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951677/).

Comment: yeah, i tried first to login in then i get the access token, then i use `lHTTP.Get('https://www.instagram.com/Myusername/');` to get the access token. Finally get the `lHTTP.Get('https://www.instagram.com/Myusername/following/');` but there is no usernames in the decrypted html, i dont think this the right method @RemyLebeau

Comment: if you want help here, you need to show the code you have tried. Anything you can do in a web browser can be done with `TIdHTTP` with the right code, so you have to be missing something.

Comment: this code is working, its just getting the source code of the page `https://www.instagram.com/Myusername/following/`. but there is no usernames in the source code while there is in the webpage itself. However, i've updated the post @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line:

```pascal
lHTTP.Get('https://www.instagram.com/myusername/following/', TStream(nil));
```

You are telling `Get()` to ignore the response body (`AResponseContent=nil`), and then you are not assigning the new response to your `Reply` variable, so you are displaying the old `Reply` value from the earlier login response.

To get the HTML of the `/following` page, use this instead

```pascal
Reply := lHTTP.Get('https://www.instagram.com/myusername/following/');
```

However, if you look at the actual HTTP requests that a web browser makes, you will see that clicking on the `Following` link on your profile page actually sends an AJAX `POST` request to the following URL to receive a JSON document listing the followers:

```
https://www.instagram.com/query/
```

Containing a query string in the `POST` body. You need to replicate that AJAX request, eg:

```pascal
var
  //...
  userid: string; // <-- add this
begin
  // after your AJAX login...

  lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36';
  lHTTP.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
  lHTTP.Get('https://www.instagram.com/myusername/', TStream(nil));

  cookie := lHTTP.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Cookie['csrftoken', 'www.instagram.com'];
  if cookie <> nil then
    token := cookie.Value
  else
    token := '';

  cookie := lHTTP.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Cookie['ds_user_id', 'www.instagram.com'];
  if cookie <> nil then
    userid := cookie.Value; // <-- add this

  Params.Clear;
  Params.Add('q=ig_user(' + userid + ') {'+LF+
           '  follows.first(10) {'+LF+
           '    count,'+LF+
           '    page_info {'+LF+
           '      end_cursor,'+LF+
           '      has_next_page'+LF+
           '    },'+LF+
           '    nodes {'+LF+
           '      id,'+LF+
           '      is_verified,'+LF+
           '      followed_by_viewer,'+LF+
           '      requested_by_viewer,'+LF+
           '      full_name,'+LF+
           '      profile_pic_url,'+LF+
           '      username'+LF+
           '    }'+LF+
           '  }'+LF+
           '}'+LF);
Params.Add('ref=relationships::follow_list');

lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-CSRFToken'] := token;
lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Instagram-AJAX'] := '1';
lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Requested-With'] := 'XMLHttpRequest';
lHTTP.Request.Referer := 'https://www.instagram.com/myusername/';
lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36';
Reply := lHTTP.Post('https://www.instagram.com/query/', Params);

// process Reply as needed ...
```

Now `Reply` should receive JSON containing the first 10 followers in your list.

Comment: how could i forget that !, i should have monitored the network before viewing the following list, Many Thanks.

Comment: you **really** should be using Instagram's [developer API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) instead of scraping HTTP traffic annually. The API supports "likes", "followers", etc. You are making things harder on yourself by not using the API. What if Instagram decides to make changes to their website in the future? Your code could break. The API would be more stable and reliable. You don't need to be a big company to get those permissions, they are granted as part of your authentication review when your app goes live and users authorize it to access their accounts.

Comment: Thanks Remy, there is `end_cursor` string each time i download the Post json, if i wanted to get all the followers list i have to get the `end_cursor` string and use it in `follows.after(end_cusror string, 1000)`. but the process is very slow, is there a way to speed this up ?

Comment: If you need help with processing the JSON, please post a new question for this. This question is for how to download the JSON, and it has been answered.

Comment: No, its about retrieving the JSON, when you download the first JSON there is  `end_cursor` string, then you use the this string here again `follows.after(end_cusror string, 1000)`  instead of `follows.first(1000) `, to get the next set of usernames, so i made a for loop to get all the usernames using this scenario.

Comment: @GBg in what way? You need to be more specific

Comment: @RemyLebeau
i login to Instagram

change code to `code`cookie := lHTTP.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Cookie['csrftoken', 'instagram.com'];
cookie := lHTTP.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Cookie['ds_user_id', 'instagram.com'];
lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Instagram-AJAX'] := '0';
`code`
when i call lHTTP.Post show error 405 method not allowed

Comment: @GBg why did you change the code? It was working fine at the time I posted it. So, either Instagram changed their requirements, or you are doing something wrong. Either way, I stand by my earlier comment that you should NOT be mimicking a web browser to access Instagram in this manner at all.  Instagram has [application APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram) for accessing and managing data. Use those APIs instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Instagram changed their requirements , I don`t khow how to use Instagram API

Comment: @GBg “*I don’t know how to use Instagram API*” - that is a whole other subject of its own. Feel free to ask new questions about that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I checked the API and started a program, but I got to the point where I wanted to get the list of followers, I saw that this feature has been removed from the API and the list can not be read, so I have to use it again. What is your suggestion?